# Unable to change file name after File Upload using WebApi MultipartFormDataStreamProvider

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, multipart

Im using WebApi to upload a file, but when I run

```
request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)
```

The file is uploaded but its file name is totally changed.
I read something about that says that it is automatically made for security reasons. Anyway I want to store the file with the real file name. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This simple override fix this issue

```
public class MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path)
    { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        // override the filename which is stored by the provider (by default is bodypart_x)
        string originalFileName = headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');

        return originalFileName;
    }
}
```